# drawInRect error: CGContextSetFont: invalid context 0x0

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, grand-central-dispatch

I draw some text to UIVIew in `drawRect:`. First I calculate text height and then `drawInRect:`. The code bellow works:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGFloat titleHeight = [self heightForText:_entry.title
                                     withFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0f]];

    CGRect r = CGRectMake(54, 6, kCellTextWidth, titleHeight);
    [_entry.title drawInRect:r withFont:[UIFont titleFont]];
}
```

Then I calculate text height with `dispatch_async` and drawInRect in main_queue, it fails:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        CGFloat titleHeight = [self heightForText:_entry.title
                                         withFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0f]];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            CGRect r = CGRectMake(54, 6, kCellTextWidth, titleHeight);
            [_entry.title drawInRect:r withFont:[UIFont titleFont]];
        });
    });
}
```

error:

```
 <Error>: CGContextSetFont: invalid context 0x0
 <Error>: CGContextSetTextMatrix: invalid context 0x0
 <Error>: CGContextSetFontSize: invalid context 0x0
 <Error>: CGContextSetTextPosition: invalid context 0x0
 <Error>: CGContextShowGlyphsWithAdvances: invalid context 0x0
```

What's the error mean? **How can I calculate text height in another thread in order to improve speed?**

Thank you.

Comment: As dispatch_async block **does not allow changes made to UI**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use CoreGraphics and CoreText APIs from secondary threads.

There are only very few UIKit APIs which are safe to call from secondary threads. As a general rule, UIKit APIs are intended for the main thread only.

The error means that `NULL` contexts are being passed to CG-APIs. The secondary threads do not create one by default -- you must create your own rendering context and destination to render on a secondary thread. UIKit calls just grab the top context on the thread's context stack -- the context stack does not exist on the secondary thread, or in this context.

As far as speed -- it's hard to believe one label would cause such a noticeable slow down. Perhaps more context would help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There is more other labels and subView on the cell, I just put one here for code example. You are right, it's not safe to call `drawInRect:` from secondary thread, Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue and solved it with `UIGraphicsPushContext(context)/UIGraphicsPopContext(context)` around the drawing code. context was created with

```
CGColorSpaceRef space = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(); CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, width, height, 8, 0, space, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
```

Comment: can you elaborate a bit more on this? I am not sure what's happening here.

Comment: I only created a context and pushed it on the graphic context stack before any drawing as stated.